# android on back pressed

Tags: android, button, back

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
        Homepage1.super.onBackPressed();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

> Error:(51, 42) error: ';' expected Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler
>   error output for details.

Comment: what is `Homepage1.super.onBackPressed();` use finish instead.

Comment: same error after repalced

Comment: which is line number 51?

Comment: public void onBackPressed()

Comment: use `this` instead `getBaseContext()`.

Comment: There is a semicolon missong on line 51.

Comment: Is that block inside another method? It needs to be directly in the `Activity`, not inside anything else.

Comment: same error , after putting  this

Comment: thanks erroe solved @Mike M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this method inside `Activity` class.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()){
                    Homepage1.super.onBackPressed();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
    }
}
```